# Embedding a conditional statement in a function

Tags: python, function

So I have created a function which used the taylor series to approximate arctan(x). Given below:

```
def arctan(x,n):

    arctang=0

    for i in range(n):
     sign=(-1)**i
     arctang = arctang + ((x**(2.0*i+1))/(2.0*i+1))*sign

    return arctang

print("arctan(x)=", arctan(x,n))
```

The user inputs a value of x between -1 and 1, and an integer for n. But I want to be able to extend the function such that the user may input any value of x, going by the statements that

if x>0, arctan(x)=(pi/2)-arctan(1/x)

if x<0, arctan(x)=-(pi/2)-arctang(1/x)

so I changed the function to the following:

```
import math


def arctan(x, n):
    arctang=0
    inv_x=1/x
    for i in range(n):
     sign=(-1)**i
     arctang = arctang + ((inv_x**(2.0*i+1))/(2.0*i+1))*sign
     if x>0:
        arc_tan=(math.pi/2)-arctang

    else:
        arc_tan=-(math.pi/2)-arctang
    return arc_tan

print("arctan(x)=", arctan(x,n))
```

however when I choose arbitrary values for x and n, eg: x=1 and n =20, the function returns an incorrect value. I don't see any errors in my equations used.

If anyone can spot what's wrong would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: That `if` statement isn't indented correctly: it's inside the `for` loop. You should use consistent indentation. The PEP-8 style guide recommends 4 spaces per indentation level.

Comment: Well for starters, your indentation doesnt look accurate in your updated function. Can you fix that?

Comment: Also, your calculations should use whichever of `x` or `inv_x` is <= 1 (this series converges _extremely_ slowly for x==1). BTW, you can improve that algorithm in a few ways. You can get rid of the `**` operations. (For float powers, Python calculates powers using logarithms, which is slow and has more error than simple multiplication). Initialize `sign = 1` outside the loop then do `sign = -sign` inside the loop. Similarly, calculate `x*x` outside the loop, and then use it as a multiplier in the loop.

Comment: Did the original function work?

Comment: Are you asking us if your math is correct or if you have an error in your code?

Comment: The original function works- but the new one returns inaccurate values

Comment: It was simply the indentation- thank you @PM2Ring. You are right though- it converges very slowly. I'm not sure I fully understand what you mean by initialising it outside the loop. Where does the i come in? It's needed to determine the sign

Comment: @Soffie Hopefully my answer explains those points.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a Python 2 / Python 3 implementation of the Taylor series for arctangent that uses the optimizations I mentioned in the comments. It also handles `abs(x) > 1`. The series does converge for `-1 <= x <= 1` (although that convergence is *very* slow as we approach the endpoints of that range), but it's simpler if we just make `x` positive.

To perform exponentiation with a float power (either with the `**` operator or the `pow` function), Python uses logarithms, which is slower than simple multiplication, and it usually has a little more error than multiplication. Of course we *could* get rid of that float power by changing `x**(2.0*i+1)` to `x**(2*i+1)`, but it's better to avoid exponentiation whenever it's practical to do so.

We can do that here because the power of `x` of each term in the series is 2 greater than that of the previous term. So we can calculate `x²` outside the loop, and use it as a multiplier in the loop to calculate each required power of `x` from the previous one.

Also, there's absolutely no need here to calculate the sign using `(-1)**i`. The sign alternates on each term, so we can initialize `sign` outside the loop, and then negate it on each loop iteration.

My test code uses `x` values that will converge fairly quickly. It calls the `atan` function from the math module to check how close our approximation is to the correct value.

```
from __future__ import print_function, division
from math import pi, atan

def arctan(x, terms):
    argsign = -1 if x < 0 else 1
    x *= argsign
    if x > 1:
        x = 1 / x
        inverted = True
    else:
        inverted = False

    result = term = x
    x2 = x * x
    sign = -1
    for i in range(3, 2 * terms, 2):
        term *= x2
        result += sign * term / i
        sign = -sign

    if inverted:
        result = pi / 2 - result
    return argsign * result

# Tests
m = 0.1
terms = 10

print('        x:   arctan(x)           diff')
fmt = '{0:9.5f}: {1:11.8f} {2:14.8g}'

for i in range(1, 10):
    x = m * i
    y = arctan(x, terms)
    print(fmt.format(x, y, y - atan(x)))
print()

for i in range(1, 10):
    x = -m * i
    y = arctan(x, terms)
    print(fmt.format(x, y, y - atan(x)))
print()

for i in range(1, 10):
    x = 1 / (m * i)
    y = arctan(x, terms)
    print(fmt.format(x, y, y - atan(x)))
print()

for i in range(1, 10):
    x = -1 / (m * i)
    y = arctan(x, terms)
    print(fmt.format(x, y, y - atan(x)))
print()
```

**output**

```
        x:   arctan(x)           diff
  0.10000:  0.09966865 -2.7755576e-17
  0.20000:  0.19739556 -8.3266727e-17
  0.30000:  0.29145679 -4.6035398e-13
  0.40000:  0.38050638 -1.8275848e-10
  0.50000:  0.46364759 -1.8491727e-08
  0.60000:  0.54041871 -7.8657695e-07
  0.70000:  0.61070757 -1.8390105e-05
  0.80000:  0.67446342 -0.00027752053
  0.90000:  0.72981546  -0.0029996458

 -0.10000: -0.09966865  2.7755576e-17
 -0.20000: -0.19739556  8.3266727e-17
 -0.30000: -0.29145679  4.6035398e-13
 -0.40000: -0.38050638  1.8275848e-10
 -0.50000: -0.46364759  1.8491727e-08
 -0.60000: -0.54041871  7.8657695e-07
 -0.70000: -0.61070757  1.8390105e-05
 -0.80000: -0.67446342  0.00027752053
 -0.90000: -0.72981546   0.0029996458

 10.00000:  1.47112767  -2.220446e-16
  5.00000:  1.37340077              0
  3.33333:  1.27933953  4.6029847e-13
  2.50000:  1.19028995  1.8275848e-10
  2.00000:  1.10714874  1.8491727e-08
  1.66667:  1.03037761  7.8657695e-07
  1.42857:  0.96008875  1.8390105e-05
  1.25000:  0.89633291  0.00027752053
  1.11111:  0.84098087   0.0029996458

-10.00000: -1.47112767   2.220446e-16
 -5.00000: -1.37340077              0
 -3.33333: -1.27933953 -4.6029847e-13
 -2.50000: -1.19028995 -1.8275848e-10
 -2.00000: -1.10714874 -1.8491727e-08
 -1.66667: -1.03037761 -7.8657695e-07
 -1.42857: -0.96008875 -1.8390105e-05
 -1.25000: -0.89633291 -0.00027752053
 -1.11111: -0.84098087  -0.0029996458
```

Note that the arctangent function in a well-written math library does *not* use the simple Taylor series. There are more sophisticated algorithms which converge faster for values near ±1, and which are less prone to the rounding errors of floating-point arithmetic.